# Second MVC form does not post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My project has two models and I am showing the first model in the first page.  The post process works great and I can see all the data.  The controller builds the second model and show the second page.  This second page will not post at all.  It won't even validate the required fields at all.  I am new to MVC so there is most likely something obvious that I am missing.  Can someone point me in a direction, some key things to look for?

I can't really share a lot of code due to security.  But basically, the first form is just a simple model, loaded with textboxfor helpers and does validate.  When posted the second model is called and the page shown.  But it won't validate at all or post.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult TourRequest()
 {
    PointofContactModel model = new PointofContactModel();
    return View(model);
 }
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionaResult TourRequest(PointofContactModel model)
 {
    model.validate(this);
    model.save(this);
    TourModel tourModel = new TourModel();
    return View("TourDetails", tourModel);
 }
```

That's basically it.  I'm starting each form with @Html.BeginForm stuff and they look right once they are rendered - looking at view source.

For some reason I am unable to add a comment to any post, even my own!  I tried what was recommended by redirecting and doing the HttpGet for the TourModel, but that page still does not validate or post.  I am lost.

First page:

```
 @model Requests.Web.Models.PointofContactModel
 @using (Html.BeginForm("TourRequest", "RequestController", FormMethod.Post))
 {
  // fields filled in
 }
```

Second page, pretty much the same, with different model

```
 @model Requests.Web>Models.TourModel
 @using (Html.BeginForm("TourDetails", "RequestController", FormMethod.Post))
 {
   //stuff
 }
```

Comment: maybe you miss the form

Comment: do you have a code sample?

Comment: You need to post your action methods and possibly your view code, just remove the sensitive parts.

Comment: @mxmissile - posted as much as I could retype for right now.  Cannot do a copy and paste unfortunately, on a separate net.

Comment: Can you post the HTML? I think I know what your problem is but I cannot be sure.

Comment: try below  answer comment if problem persists...

Comment: then post relevant code also plz..

Comment: I know this is going to sound like a dumb question, but do you have a button within the using statement with `type="submit"`. If not, there is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the most simple thing is right in front of you and you miss it.  I had the submit button on the second form OUTSIDE of the @HTML.BEGINFORM brackets.  Stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can't be certain without looking at your code but try this.

In your HTML use the following code:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("TourDetails", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    // You don't necessarily need this, but if you already do then you need to put
    // [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on the top of your action
{
```

The structure of your controller is sound, I'm reckoning the problem is because you have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` but you aren't choosing to validate it by the controller, this in turn may be causing an un-handled exception.

Alternatively, you could do the following if all else fails (put the anti forgery validation in if you're using that in the view):

```
public ActionResult TourRequest()
{
     //Do the HTTPGET stuff here
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("TourRequest")]
public ActionResult TourRequestPostRequest()
{
     // Do the post method stuff here
}
```

Please bare in mind, this is only a guess as I cannot see your code in the view.

Answer (score -1):

Just correct this in your post controller :

Just remove these lines

```
 TourModel tourModel = new TourModel();
 return View("TourDetails", tourModel);
```

and write this

```
return RedirectToAction("TourDetails");
```

Your `TourDetails` action will look like this :

```
[HttpGet]
Public ActionResult TourDetails
{
   TourModel tourModel = new TourModel();
   //bind model here if required
   retrun View(tourModel);
}
```

Please bare in mind, this is only a guess as you are not posting code in the view.

In your edit change RequestController to only Request in BeginForm() .

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the difference?

Comment: @JTMon...when we use return view() just the html is returned to the view and there is no change in url in browser and nothing else but with redirecttoaction a new http(302) request is generated and url in browser changes.

Comment: I understand the difference between return view and RedirectToAction. I was just wondering how it relates to original question and the no posting issue.

Comment: @JTMon...i don't think its a good idea that you are on a different view having url of a different view in browser..

Comment: Regarding your recent comment, what do you mean?